# CAR Application Deployment doesn't deploy Axis service

Tags: deployment, apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB (4.7.0), I have added application server feature (4.1.0).  My carbon app contains the following artefacts

1. AxisService (aar)
2. AxisClientStub (lib)
3. Mediator (synapse-mediator) that uses the client stub
4. Error Sequence
5. Main Sequence (Uses mediator 3)
6. Out Sequence
7. REST Api (using the 4,5,6)

When I deploy this CAR file in the ESB, it starts deploying from 3 onwards and cribs that it does not find the client stub library.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Need to resolve this urgently, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer studio by default, for axis service, capp property is set as capp/ApplicationServer.  I changed this to capp/EnterpriseServiceBus.  With this change, I am able to deploy my axis services in the ESB thru carbon application

```
    <com.xx.yyy:CCCService:1.1-SNAPSHOT>capp/EnterpriseServiceBus</com.xx.yyy:CCCService:1.1-SNAPSHOT>
```

Comment: Even without Application server feature, axis services can be deployed in ESB 4.7.0 thru CAR deployment